# What is wrong with my MySql query

Tags: mysql, select

```
SELECT WEEK(STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y' ),1) as order_week,
        YEAR(STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y' ),1) as order_year
FROM orders_products_attributes
```

If it's just the week I don't get any error, but as soon as I try to select the year as well, it throws

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1) as order_year FROM orders_products_attributes'...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y' ),1)
```

with

```
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y' ))
```

There is no second parameter for the `YEAR()` function. Or you could just do

```
STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%Y' )
```

Answer (score 0):

use this sql

```
SELECT WEEK(STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y' ),1) as order_week, 
       YEAR(STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y' )) as order_year
FROM orders_products_attributes
```

for further reading
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

Answer (score 0):

Improper use of `YEAR()` method. second paramater should not be there. 
Try this one:

```
SELECT WEEK(STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y' ),1) 
as order_week, 
YEAR(STR_TO_DATE( products_options_values, '%m-%d-%Y' )) as order_year
FROM orders_products_attributes
```